# How to get the object in a matrix when clicked

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a matrix of cells placed in a custom view.

I want to select the cell when it is clicked to change the colour from red to green.

[Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuXym.png)

**Board**

```
class Board : View {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): super(context, attrs)

    // Paint object for coloring and styling
    private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private val board_col = Color.CYAN
    private val size = 1000
    private lateinit var board : Array<Array<Cell>>




    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        // call the super method to keep any drawing from the parent side.
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        board(canvas)
        initGrid(canvas)
        grid(canvas)
    }


    private fun board(canvas: Canvas){
        paint.color = board_col
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        canvas.save()
        val board_rec = Rect(0,0,size,size)
        canvas.drawRect(board_rec, paint)
        canvas.restore()
    }

    private fun initGrid(canvas: Canvas): Array<Array<Cell>> {
        val array = Array(10) { Array(10){Cell(0,0,0,0,0,0, canvas)} }
        var dim = size / 10
        for(i in 0 until array.size) {
            for (j in 0 until array[i].size) {
                var px = i * dim
                var py = j * dim
                array [i][j] = Cell(i, j, px, py, px + dim, py + dim, canvas)
            }
        }
        Log.i("TAG", "initGrid: " + array.size.toString())
       return array
    }



    private fun grid(canvas: Canvas){
        board = initGrid(canvas)
        for(i in 0 until board.size) {
            for (j in 0 until board.size) {
                board[i][j].show()
            }
        }
    }

    //TODO: 19:48 View Pressed
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                for(i in 0 until board.size) {
                    for (j in 0 until board.size) {
                        if (board[i][j].contain(board[i][j].coorX(), board[i][j].coorY())) {
                            Log.i("TAG", "initGrid: " + board[i][j].coorX())

                        }
                    }
                }
                invalidate()
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

}
```

This is the Board class where I populate the Cells.

The cells have the following attributes

i,j: location in matrix

px,py: where the cell is drawn

px + dim, py + dim: how big the cell is displayed

**Cell**

```
class Cell(var col : Int , var row : Int, x : Int, y: Int, w: Int, h: Int,canvas: Canvas){
    var x = x
    var y = y
    var w= w
    var canvas = canvas

    // Paint object for coloring and styling
    val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)

    var r = Rect(x,y,w,h)

    fun show(){
        paint.color = Color.BLACK
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        canvas.save()
        canvas.drawRect(r,paint)
        canvas.restore()
        paint.color = Color.WHITE
        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        paint.strokeWidth = 4.0f
        canvas.save()
        canvas.drawRect(r,paint)
        canvas.restore()
    }

    fun contain(x: Int, y: Int) : Boolean{
        Log.i("TAG", "Location: " + x)

        return (x > this.x && x < this.x + this.w && y > this.y && y < this.y + this.w)
    }

    fun changeBtn(){
        paint.color = Color.RED
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        canvas.drawRect(r,paint)
        canvas.restore()
    }

    fun coorX(): Int {
        return x
    }

    fun coorY(): Int {
        return y
    }

}
```

I am following this tutorial but it is in JS, the time wher I am is 19:30

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFU5ZlrR21E&t=1188s

When my `onTouchEvent()` is called it checks the the cell function `contains()` and is supposed to return the coordinates of the cell (according to the video) which I could then use to change the colour of the button. But it does not work in Kotlin here is the list of the first 10 coordinates.

How can I change the Cell colour when it is clicked on?

[Coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfn9E.png)

Comment: There are several problems here, more than I have time to explain how to fix. But just some quick ones...If you intend to change the color of cells, then the Cell class will have to be able to hold the state of whether it has switched colors. Therefore, you cannot be calling `initGrid` in `onDraw()` or you will lose that state before it can be drawn. You also can't be using a fixed size of 1000 pixels for your board, because Android screens come in many different dimensions,...

Comment: so the size should be relative to view width, but you can only get proper view width in `onDraw` because the width is zero before it's been measured for the first time, and it's width might change depending on what happens to it in the layout. For these reasons, I would not give the Cell class any information about position and size. They should only have row and column coordinates. The parent class can determine which cell was hit by doing some math relative to its own size. This is more sensible than iterating them all anyway.

Comment: Basically, canvases must be handled quite differently on Android than they do for a web page because Android canvases work with literal pixels that will vary in size based on screen density. It will not be trivial to adapt that tutorial. Anyways, I see a bug in the last line of your `contain` function. The last `this.w` should be `this.h`. But the whole line could be replaced with `return r.contains(x, y)`.

Comment: You also can't just draw a different colored rectangle one time onto your canvas in the middle of the `onTouch` function. Even if that worked, the change would be immediately lost on the next invalidation or the next time the view is redrawn.

Comment: @Tenfour04: Thanks for the advice I will change my approach